# Functions as types in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have confusion using types which are functions.

Let say I want to implement a dictionary, which when given a and b returns Maybe b.

```
type Dict a b = a->Maybe b
```

**How can I implement an insertion function for this dictionary?**

```
insertDict :: (Eq a) => a -> b -> (Dict a b)-> (Dict a b)
```

I have come up with the following thing

```
insertDict x y mydict = \a->Just y
```

but it is not correct and will discard the previous dictionary.

Comment: By insertion do you mean a function which mutates its arguments? If so, you aren't thinking functionality.

Comment: @JohnColeman Disagree, the function he is proposing returns a new dictionary. Seems pretty functional to me.

Comment: @danidiaz How do you disagree with a question? I just wanted OP to clarify their intention. The last sentence in their question about discarding the previous dictionary led me to wonder if they were hoping to modify it instead.

Comment: @JohnColeman I interpreted the last sentence to mean that the information carried by the old dictionary was being ignored when defining the new one.

Comment: @danidiaz I think that you interpreted them correctly. Your answer cleared things up for me.

Comment: This won't help directly, but I generally recommend that newcomers avoid writing type synonyms (like your `Dict`), and that experienced Haskell programmers use them in strict moderation. They tend to be more confusing and less valuable than you'd expect. I suggest you instead try `newtype Dict a b = Dict { unDict :: a -> b }`. This will require you to wrap and unwrap dictionaries when implementing the basic functions, but you'll be able to make `Dict` an abstract datatype by keeping the constructor private to the module, and you'll make it very clear which functions represent dictionaries.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a "chain of responsibility" pattern: the insert function checks if the argument to the *result* `Dict` matches with its own key, otherwise it delegates on the previous `Dict` which received as argument.

```
type Dict a b = a -> Maybe b

insertDict :: (Eq a) => a -> b -> Dict a b -> Dict a b
-- Note that the k' is the argument of the result dict function
insertDict k v dict k' = if k == k' then Just v else dict k'

emptyDict :: Dict a b
emptyDict _ = Nothing
```

Some examples in ghci:

```
Λ insertDict 'a' (1::Int) emptyDict $ 'a'
Just 1
Λ insertDict 'b' 2 (insertDict 'a' (1::Int) emptyDict) $ 'a'
Just 1
Λ insertDict 'b' 2 (insertDict 'a' (1::Int) emptyDict) $ 'x'
Nothing
```

Representing maps as functions is good as a first approximation, but this representation has a number of drawbacks:

- The complexity of searching for a value is linear in the number of keys.
- Functions are pretty "opaque", which means you can't inspect or serialize the map as you could do if you had used a [data type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html).

Comment: Writing it as `insertDict k v dict = \k' -> if k == k' then Just v else dict k'` might make it clearer.

Comment: Also, the reason for making the dict the last argument of the function is to allow chaining via composition: `insertDict 'b' 2 . insertDict 'a' 1 . emptyDict $ 'a'`.

Answer (score 11):

Here’s one method you can use to help write such functions yourself. First, write the type signature:

```
insertDict :: (Eq k) => k -> v -> Dict k v -> Dict k v
```

I’ve used `k` and `v` for “key” and “value” here for clarity. Next, start by writing the implementation as a *hole*:

```
insertDict key value dict
  = _
```

The compiler (or GHCi) should give you a message like “Found hole: `_ :: Dict k v` […] Relevant bindings include: `dict :: Dict k v`, `value :: v`, `key :: k`. So here you see that you *could* just return `dict` because the type matches, but that would ignore `key` and `value`.

Since you know that `Dict k v` is a function type, you can make progress by adding a lambda with another hole to see what the compiler offers:

```
insertDict key value dict
  = \ key' -> _
```

Now we have `_ :: Maybe v`, `value :: v`, `key' :: k`, `key' :: k`, `dict :: Dict k v`. We could always return `Just value`, but as you observed, that doesn’t do what we want—it represents a dictionary that always answers “Yes, that key is in the dictionary and its value is `value`” for any key you ask about! (That is a useful thing to be able to represent, it’s just not the thing we’re writing.)

So it doesn’t look like we can make progress with just these—but wait, we also have an `Eq k` constraint! And the only two things we can compare are `key` and `key'`, so let’s expand this into an `if` using `==`:

```
insertDict key value dict
  = \ key' -> if key == key' then _1 else _2
```

Now the compiler reports `_1 :: Maybe v` and `_2 :: Maybe v`. What should we return in each of these cases? Let’s consider some examples of how this function is actually used—if you look up a key in a dictionary after inserting a key-value pair, you should of course find the value:

```
(insertDict key value dict) key == Just value
                                   ----------
```

So for `_1` we can write `Just value`:

```
insertDict key value dict
  = \ key' -> if key == key' then Just value else _2
                                  ----------
```

If you look up a *different* key than the one you just inserted, then the most recently inserted key-value pair doesn’t matter; it should look up the key further on in the dictionary:

```
(insertDict key value dict) key' == dict key'  -- If key /= key'
                                    ---------
```

So for `_2` we can write `dict key'`:

```
insertDict key value dict
  = \ key' -> if key == key' then Just value else dict key'
                                                  ---------
```

And we’re done! :D

This combination of *type-directed programming* and *equational reasoning* is very helpful when writing in Haskell, especially for polymorphic functions like this that have a limited number of possible (sane) implementations.